# AngularJS $modal 2 way binding to $scope doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My $scope variables are not updating based on values placed in input fields in the modal.  In the below code, $scope.markup is always 0, even when I change the input field to another value.  What is wrong with this code?

To Open the modal:

```
$scope.openCalculator = function() {
    $modal.open({
        templateUrl: '/Scripts/templates/modalMarkupCalculator.html',
        controller: 'modalMarkupCalculatorCtrl',
        windowClass: 'modal-markup-calculator'
    });
```

modalMarkupCalculator.html:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">Markup and Discount Calculator</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-7 control-label">Markup %</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="number"
                       class="form-control"
                       ng-model="markup"
                       ng-change="markupChanged()"
                       ng-enabled="markupEditable" />
            </div>
        </div>
     </form>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="close()">Close</button>
</div>
```

modalMarkupCalculatorCtrl.js

```
myApp.controller('modalMarkupCalculatorCtrl', [
    '$modalInstance', '$scope', function ($modalInstance, $scope) {
        $scope.markup = 0;

        $scope.markupChanged = function() {
                    // $scope.markup is always 0 here!!  It should be what the input is changed to!
            if (!$scope.markup) {
                $scope.clientDiscountEditable = false;
            } else {
                $scope.clientDiscountEditable = true;
            }
        }

        $scope.close = function () {
            $modalInstance.dismiss('close');
        };
    }
]);
```

Comment: I would try: 1. print {{markup}} to see rather it is changing. 2.use markup as an object to avoid isolated scope \ inheritance issue's. 3.change markupChanged() to receive a markup as a variable and pass markup from the html

Comment: Is the $scope shared with the parent?  It could be variables that are used in the parent.

Comment: scope is inherited from parent (prototypical inheritance)

Comment: I changed the variable to a unique variable and it does update on the screen where I'm using {{markup}}.  However the markupChanged() is called before the $scope markup value updates.. how do I call a function after it updates?

Comment: For some reason $watch does not work in the modal.. not sure why it works fine on my other pages.. that's the route I went down first.

Comment: I had to put my values within an object in the scope and it works fine now using $watch.